# Important Carrier Message "Unlock iPhone to view message"

Tags: iphone, security, unlock, sim

Yesterday I made an update to the latest iOS version. Now I have to unlock the phone to enter the passcode for Mobile ID (2FA authentication).

Before the update, I could enter the Mobile ID passcode without unlocking.

How can I reset to the previous behavior?

> Protect access to your company data and applications with a
> comprehensive end-to-end solution for [two-factor authentication (2FA)](https://www.swisscom.ch/en/business/enterprise/offer/security/mobileid.html).
> Simple installation and high compatibility allow quick set-up at home
> and abroad so you can log on to online applications securely, wherever
> you are.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sim replacement fixed the issue.

Comment: I have eSIM. So not a solution for me.